# Bottom Navigation Bar in Android Studio not Working?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

```
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            when (it.itemId){

                R.id.local1 -> make_Fragment(fragment1)
                R.id.local2-> make_Fragment(fragment2)
                R.id.local3 -> make_Fragment(fragment3)
            }
            true

     }
```

Here bottomNavigationView is throwing error :  `Unresolved reference: bottomNavigationView` and also i defined the id on `mainactivity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.MainActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_wapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigationView"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here `bottomNavigationView` shows error and also `when(it.itemId){`
the `bottomNavigationView` is the id of the bottom bar.i also tried clean project and rebuild project.

> tell me a solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: Which of the two are you using, viewBinding or kotlin synthetics?

Comment: If you are not using viewbinding get the view by findViewById

Comment: where is the reference for bottomNavigationView, Is you are using data binding or view binding you must need to mension in question? Please modify the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

add these in `build.gradle(:app)`

```
   id 'kotlin-android'
   id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

this in dependencies
   `implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"`
like this

```
dependencies {

    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10" }
```

add this import statement in `MainActivity.kt`

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.mainactivity.*
```

it will work just fine :)...

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependencies in build.gradle

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
```

Add kotlin code implementation
Please refer this my github repository for better understanding.

https://github.com/meshramaravind/BottomNavigtaionApp